# Determining how a site is being accessed in IIS 7

Tags: iis, bindings

I have a hosted dedicated server with a site in IIS 7.5. This site has various bindings that allow external access to it (www.foo.com, www.bar.com, www.baz.com). I would like to know how i can have statistics of how the site is being accessed. How many times it was accessed through www.foo.com, for example. How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't configuring IIS to log the cs-host property allow you to see what site they were visiting?

Comment: Thanks Joe. I think this is the best way of doing what I want. Now I need a good log parser. Do you know a good one?

Comment: I don't do a lot of IIS log parsing, but I have used this in the past: http://www.weblogexpert.com. If I remember correctly they have a scaled down free version and a feature packed paid version.

Answer (score 1):

Use IIS Advance Logging option that would be helpful. There are also Options are available to write logs with options available as following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms524602.aspx
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/579/advanced-logging-for-iis-70---custom-logging/

Gaurav Maniar MCP | MCSE | MCST | MCITP | ITILv3 Certified

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP installed, you could write a script with the SERVER_NAME or HTTP_HOST variable and include it on the index page.

Some pseudocode:

```
if visitor HTTP_HOST = www.foo.com
then increase $foocount by 1
else if visitor HTTP_HOST = www.bar.com
then increase $barcount by 1
else if visitor HTTP_HOST = www.baz.com
then increase $bazcount by 1
```

$foocount, $barcount, $bazcount could be anything from a text file to a database.
It could also mean "load specific 1x1 pixel image", and then see how many times each pixel image has been accessed. As long as you know about HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME, there are many ways to implement a visitor counter.

Answer (score 0):

Um, [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)?